# Cant seem to find the cause of Not Null Failed error

Tags: python

Now I am running into a minor issue and I know it is something small but I am getting programmers block and cant seem to figure out where this error is coming from. I am creating a way to send friends request to other users.

What happens is that the person logged in will search fro a user and get directed to their profile. There is then an add friend link that will send the loggedin user record and searched user record. then it will grab both of thier usernames and save them in the database table and add a status.

block of code from the relationship.py file:

```
def Send_Valid_Request(User, Request):

    newRequest = Friends(User_1 = User.Username,
                         User_2 = Request.Username,
                         Status = 1)
    db_session.add(newRequest)
    db_session.commit()

    relationship = db_session.query(Friends).\
                        filter(and_(Friends.User_1 == User.Username,
                                    Friends.User_2 == Request.Username)).\
                        filter(Friends.Status == 1).\
                        first()

    if relationship == None:
        flash('There was an error with the request')
        return redirect(url_for('UserProfile', current_user = Request.Username))
    else:
        flash('A request to ' + Request.Username + ' has been sentf')
        return redirect(url_for('Home'))
```

Here is the table:

```
class Friends(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'friends'

    ID = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    User_1 = Column(String(22), nullable = False, index = True)
    User_2 = Column(String(22), nullable = False, index = True)
    Status = Column(Integer, nullable = False)
```

and here is the error that I am getting:

```
IntegrityError: (IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed: Friends.Created u'INSERT INTO friends ("User_1", "User_2", "Status") VALUES (?, ?, ?)' (u'omarjandali', u'hanijandali', 1)

Traceback (most recent call last)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/vagrant/roadtrip/website/__init__.py", line 270, in SendRequest
Send_Valid_Request(currentUser, requestUser)
File "/vagrant/roadtrip/website/relationships.py", line 57, in Send_Valid_Request
db_session.commit()
```

Comment: I deleted all the code and rebuilt the route completely and then it worked

Answer (score 0):

The error is happening because, in your `Friends` schema, you have added `ID` column but while inserting you are not providing it.

```
  ID = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
```

This happens because your `ID` column is not auto-incremented. Check your database whether it provide auto-incremented serial key.

Comment: You could also add `autoincrement=True` to the column definition if you build the schema from the models.